# Persistent 403 errors when posting an event to a group calendar via the Microsoft graph api

Tags: azure, office365, microsoft-graph-api, office365api, azure-ad-graph-api

I am attempting to create an event in a group via the Microsoft Graph Api.

I can currently Create/Update and delete groups however I am unable to interact with events inside these groups. I can also create events in calendars that are not inside a group

I have checked that I have all of the permissions as detailed in the documentation and I am not missing any that are listed. The only one listed for this API call is

```
Group.ReadWrite.All
```

However, I already have this permission (evident by being able to create and update a group)

If it helps, we are attempting to create shared calendars via the API, and it seemed that groups were the only way to achieve this.

**To Replicate**

Setup an application that calls the graph v1 API using application permissions. (Note: This issue does not occur with delegated permissions)

Give your application the following permissions

- Group.ReadWrite.All
- User.ReadWrite.All
- Calendars.ReadWrite
- Directory.ReadWrite.All

Send the following request (with the appropriate body):

```
POST /groups
```

This will work and so will the following request:

```
POST /groups/{id}/members/$ref
```

However, this request will return a 403:

```
POST /groups/{id}/calendar/events
```

and so will this

```
POST /groups/{id}/events
```

Comment: Maybe show your [mcve] so we have some context.

Comment: @jdv I have now edited this into the main post

Comment: Provided an answer [here] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54401004/add-event-to-o365-group-calendar-with-application-permission/54431768#54431768)