# Add event to O365 group calendar with "Application" permission

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, office365api, azure-ad-graph-api

**Use Case**

My application needs to dynamically create Office 365 Outlook calendars, share them with a variable number of Office 365 users, and manage the calendar events at any time.

**Approach**

Since the application needs to manage the calendars at any time, it needs to authenticate with [Application Permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#delegated-permissions-application-permissions-and-effective-permissions).

Using the [Groups API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/groups-overview), I can do the following:

1. [Create the group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-groups) (and therefore the calendar)
2. [Add members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-members)
3. [Create events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-events) (in the calendar)

**Problem**

The problem is that creating events is **["Not Supported"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-events)** when using "Application Permission".

Because of this, it seems it is not possible to achieve my Use Case.

I'd like to understand more about this:

- What is the reason for this restriction on creating events? Since Application Permission are able to create Groups, it seems inconsistent to then prevent creating events.
- Is there another way to achieve my use case, perhaps without creating groups?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Currently App permissions are not available for Group calendars, as they are for a user's calendar.

I'd suggest starting with as ask in the [Office Groups Api uservoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/search?query=group%20calendar)

Comment: Thanks for your response Kalyan. I have been using the Graph API with Application Permission to create events in users calendars for years, so not sure that the statement "event creation activity is always done by a user (or a user account)" is entirely accurate. See docs here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-events. So why can you perform this action in user calendars but not group calendars? Further, it appears to be listed as a known issue on this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues?view=graph-rest-1.0#groups.

Comment: You are right, I mixed things up at my end. Modifying my answer as its incorrect.